# tf.data API read the TFRecord files

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to use the tf.data API read the TFRecord file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

def train_input_fn():
    filenames = ["mytrain.tfrecords"]
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

    def parser(record):
        keys_to_features = {
            "image_data": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
            "date_time": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=""),
            "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64,
                                        default_value=tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int64)),
        }
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

        image = tf.decode_jpeg(parsed["image_data"])
        image = tf.reshape(image, [128, 128, 3])
        label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.int32)

        return {"image_data": image, "date_time": parsed["date_time"]}, label

    dataset = dataset.map(parser)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(32)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(1)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return features, labels

output = train_input_fn()

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord = coord)
    for i in range(230):
        image, label = sess.run(output)
        img = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
        img.save(cwd+str(i) + '_''Label_'+str(l)+'.jpg')
        print(image, label)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Tensorflow/Wenshan_Cai_Nanoletters/tf_data.py", line 34, in 
    output = train_input_fn()
  File "E:/Tensorflow/Wenshan_Cai_Nanoletters/tf_data.py", line 25, in train_input_fn
TypeError: Expected int64, got '' of type 'str' instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note `TypeError: Expected int64, got '' of type 'str' instead` from your error log. You have a bug in your code.

**The bug**

In the following line:

`"date_time": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=""),`

The default value for a `tf.int64` type variable is specified as a string `""`.

**A fix**

So say your expected default is 0, then you should change line to:

`"date_time": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have fixed this one. But there is another error. tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got empty file
  [[{{node DecodeJpeg}} = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false](ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:1)]]
  [[{{node IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?], [?,128,128,3], [?]], output_types=[DT_INT64, DT_UINT8, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]

Comment: @WENWEN It's usually recommended to create another stack-overflow question for such a new problem, instead of posting it as a comment here. As far as the original question is concerned, if my post answers your original question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.